shortest path between two points(mesh) in the glb file in three.js using React.js
I've a .glb file which is about to showcase the map. I need to find the shortest path between two points(mesh) and draw a line using Yuka . The solution should be in React.Js or R3F. Also camera should be moving on the basis of line movement.

Could you show your efforts so far?

since I'm a beginner in this topic , i haven't much to share. I got the library mentioned here got from the web. If any alternate option instead of Yuka , please suggest. Thanks in advance.

I would start by creating a basic template... Then once you are familiar with the basic concepts, I would study the implementation of this: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-pathfinding and this https://github.com/dhruvmisra/Pathfinding-Visualizer-ThreeJS and algorithms like Dijkstra’s or A*.

Ok...good to hear
